# My LAMP server does not work after moving to a new house

Tags: apache-httpd, port-forwarding, dynamic-ip

I self host two websites on a Apache2 instance that runs on a Raspberry Pi3 (more info on versions and configurations below): Website1 is a a static website that I coded from scratch, while website2 runs on Wordpress.

I used to live in an apartment where the ISP provided a static public IP but I recently moved to a new house, where the ISP does not provide that option. I have been trying to reconfigure everything but I cannot make it all work again.

### Configurations

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running the latest version of Raspbian

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
VERSION_CODENAME=stretch
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

On my router (model: `Alcatel-Lucent G240W-B`) I have opened **port XX for http** and **port YY for ssh** (I am not using standard ports to increase security)

```
Application Name | WAN Connection | WAN Port | LAN Port | Internal Client | Protocol | Status
Customer settings | {my_wan_connection} |   XX~XX | XX~XX | 192.168.1.100 | TCPorUDP | ACTIVE
Customer settings | {my_wan_connection} | YY~YY | YY~YY | 192.168.1.100 | TCPorUDP | ACTIVE
```

I am running apache2

```
$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian)
Server built:   2019-08-19T19:25:31
```

with two websites enabled

```
$ sudo apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:XX                 is a NameVirtualHost
         default server mydomain.ddns.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website1.com.conf:1)
         port XX namevhost mydomain.ddns.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website1.com.conf:1)
                 alias website1.com
                 alias www.website1.com
         port XX namevhost mydomain.ddns.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website2.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.wesbiste2.com
                 alias wesbiste2.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: MODSEC_2.5
Define: MODSEC_2.9
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Also, this is my `ports.conf`

```
$ sudo cat ports.conf 
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 0.0.0.0:XX

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I have set a dynamic DNS with NoIP (mydomain.ddns.net) which gets updated through my router

### What works and what does not

- SSH works fine, and I can connect to my raspberry pi both within my home network and from outside - when I check if door YY is open from a port checking tool I get a positive response
- HTTP is more problematic: **despite the door being closed (according to port checkers at least)** I can see website1 (which is apache's default server) from

  - internal ip address: 192.168.1.100:XX
  - public ip address: {my-public-ip}:XX
  - dynamic dns hostname mydomain.ddns.net

However, since in this ways I can only access website1, and not website2, I tried to disable website1 (`sudo a2dissite website1.com.conf`) and restart apache (`sudo systemctl restart apache2`)

```
$ sudo apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:XX                 mydomain.ddns.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website2.com.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: MODSEC_2.5
Define: MODSEC_2.9
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

However, I still cannot access website2 from internal or public ip, nor DDNS hostname.

### Changing Wordpress URL

I thought this might be related to Wordpress and indeed I found [this article](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/) and followed the instructions to [change the URL directly in the database][2]. Indeed the 'home' and 'url' values were equal to my old public static IP so I changed the to my DDNS (myhostname.ddns.net). However, the site is still unaccessible

FYI, my first priority would **to be able to access website2** and see its contents, whether through internal or external IP, or DDNS hostnmae.

Comment: This is almost certainly a Wordpress problem.  Wordpress encodes URL in the database - its a known Wordpress problem.

Comment: And if it's not Wordpress, it sounds like a generic Linux/Apache/etc problem rather than Raspberry Pi specific. You might get more attention at https://serverfault.com/.